# :x stepping down from my moderator role

Tags: discussion, moderation

As you may have noticed I've been less than active as a moderator for several months now, so I sent and email to the Stack Exchange team to step down from my position.

After being a member of this community for almost 6 years and a mod for about 3 years I have learned tremendously and I pride myself in having been useful to some of you. Now I feel like it's the right time to let a more active member of the community take on the duty of "janitor of this site" as our first historical moderator used to call this role.

Also now is a great time for a shout out to Fill and Ben who have been greatly moderating the site for the past year. You guys rock and I'm sure you'll continue to do a great job!

Comment: Always feels weird to vote up this sort of announcement, but I did it anyway. Thanks for all your hard work, and I hope we'll continue to see you around here even if less frequently.

Comment: As long as you'll still be around it's all good to me. :)

Comment: I'll definitely continue to be on the site, the community is too great to be left like this :) Also I don't know if it's of anyone's interest but I wrote [a short blog post](https://www.statox.fr/posts/vim/stepping-down-vi-se/) about my time here.

Comment: Interesting. It seems quite strange that the number of page views has been rising steadily while the posts per month is flat. Any theories? (And just FYI the reference to the site nickname "vi.se" is linked to some random Swedish page.)

Comment: @BLayer my guess is that the more people are on this site the closer we get to the [1% rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%25_rule_(Internet_culture)): In the beginning we had few member and a lot of them were creating posts but now we have about as many active users but many more lurkers. I guess it would make sense because at the beginning of the site we had a lot of "fundamental" questions and now more and more questions are about debugging... But what I'm saying is based on nothing else than a guess :) Also thanks for the note about vi.se, will fix

Comment: 1% rule, eh? I like it. I'll go with that. ;)